# this.getAttribute() returns an object how can I access to that object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Doing `this.getAttribute('data')` returns an object, how can I access to that object to return `data.id`?

If I do this returns me `[object Object]`.

```
$(".button").click(function(){
     var source = this.getAttribute('data-request');
     console.log(source);
     });
```

And this way returns `Undefined`:

```
 $(".button").click(function(){
         var result = this.getAttribute('data-request');
         console.log(result.id);
     });
```

Comment: Can you add a sample button HTML content too?

Comment: Could you show the HTML for that `.button` element.

Comment: If `this.getAttribute('data-request')` is returning `"[object Object]"`, it's because someone mistakenly did `this.setAttribute('data-request', someObject);` (or similar). Attributes can only store **strings**, so doing that automatically converts the object to string, which in most cases results in the string `"[object Object]"`. So you can't access the object, because it was never stored to start with, only this not-useful string. :-) (The reason you get `undefined` for `console.log(result.id)` is that strings don't have an `id` property.)

Comment: Please add the code where you set the `data-request` attribute

Answer (score 2):

If `this.getAttribute("data-request")` is returning `"[object Object]"`, it's because the attribute contains the string `"[object Object]"`, not because it contains an object. Most likely, someone mistakenly did `this.setAttribute("data-request", someObject);` (or similar). Attributes can only store **strings**, so doing that automatically converts the object to string, which in most cases results in the string `"[object Object]"`, and then stores that string in the attribute.

That means you can't access the object, because it was never stored to start with, instead, just the `"[object Object]"` string was stored. (The reason you get `undefined` for `console.log(result.id)` is that strings don't have an `id` property.)

Since you're using jQuery, you have access to jQuery's [`data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) function, which can store arbitrary data (which can be anything, not just a string) on a DOM element. So if you really need to store an object attached to a DOM element, find the code doing `this.setAttribute("data-request", someObject);` or `$(something).attr("data-request", someObject);` and replace it with `$(something).data("request", someObject);` That does **not** set a `data-*` attribute, but does store the data associated with the element. Then you can retrieve it with `const result = $(this).data("request");`.

Comment: Yes when I did `createElement()` I had set the attribute with `setAttibute('data-request', object)` to save the data that is an object, and inside of that object I have an id that why I want to return `result.id`

Comment: @Ryan - Cool. So you can either use the `data` function I mentioned above, or (if the `id` is a string or can easily be converted to and from a string), just store the `id` instead of the object.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this problem is to pass the attribute like a Json String with **JSON.stringify(dayBooking)** and then parse the json object

```
let dataDay = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-value")
dataDay = JSON.parse(dataDay)
```